# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'

Tags: angular-cli

I downloaded a project from a Udemy course, from there I'm going to learn. However, when I activate the ng serve -o it gives me a series of errors:

PS C:\01-hola-mundo> ng serve -o
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
  See "C:\Users\GABRIEL\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-cFPBpp\angular-errors.log" for further details.
  PS C:\01-hola-mundo>

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you download an angular project you need to do an npm install to install the dependencies. Their error says there are missing dependencies or in other words `node modules` are not there.

Solution: `npm install` *NOTE: do this in the root folder*